# get ng-click, on injected element, to change the class of an element already in the view?

Tags: angularjs

I have a <ul> that gets populated with the server. But in that controller there is also an iframe. When the <li>'s arrive there is some disconnect between them and the iframe even though they are in the same controller.

When you click one of the li's it should change the class on the iframe but it's not. However, If I move the iframe inside of the ng-repeat that injects the iframe it works.

**View**

```
    <div class="content" ng-controller="FeedListCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <div data-link="{{item.link}}" ng-click="articleShowHide='fade-in'">
                    <div ng-bind-html="item.title" style="font-weight:bold;"></div>
                    <div ng-bind-html="item.description"></div>
                    <!-- it works if i put the iframe here -->
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- doesn't work when the iframe is here -->
        <iframe id="article" ng-class="articleShowHide" src=""></iframe>
    </div>
```

Here is the controller. It does an ajax call to get the data for each <li>

**Controller**

```
readerApp.controller('FeedListCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", "FeedListUpdate", function     ($scope, $http, FeedListUpdate) {
    $scope.setFeed = function (url) {
        $http.get('feed?id=' + FeedListUpdate.GetCurrentFeedUrl()).success(function (data)     {
            $scope.items = data.currentFeed.items;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When inside of an ng-repeat you are in a different scope which means you are not setting the variable you think you are. Use $parent and that should work. The syntax is:

```
<div data-link="{{item.link}}" ng-click="$parent.articleShowHide='fade-in'">
```

Side note for others finding this - sometimes adding curly brackets helps as well. For more information on ng-class see here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

**An Example**

In case anyone wants to see this in action, I put together an example demonstrating a few ways to set the class as well as demonstrating the issue in scope (See: http://plnkr.co/edit/8gyZGzESWyi2aCL4mC9A?p=preview). It isn't very pretty but it should be pretty clear what is going on. By the way, the reason that methods work in this example is that the scope doesn't automatically redefine them the way it does variables so it is calling the method in the root scope rather than setting a variable in the repeater scope.

Best of luck!

Comment: The better way would be make articleShowHide as object and use syntax like `articleShowHide.class='fade-in'` and then bind to `articleShowHide.class` property.

Comment: @Chandermani That also works! Once the OP understands the way scope works, there are many excellent solutions!